# I wanted to change my array of object to different format

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reduce

I wanted to change my array of object to different format

I have below output,

```
let result =  [
    {
        "team_details_id": 1,
        "team_name": "Avengers",
        "team_description": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-03T09:31:13.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-03T09:31:13.000Z",
        "created_by": "23",
        "updated_by": null,
        "team_participants_id": 2,
        "user_id": 101,
        "user_name": "test 2",
        "email_id": "test2@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3,
        "is_active": 1,
        "access_code": null
    },
    {
        "team_details_id": 1,
        "team_name": "Avengers",
        "team_description": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-03T09:31:13.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-03T09:31:13.000Z",
        "created_by": "23",
        "updated_by": null,
        "team_participants_id": 3,
        "user_id": 102,
        "user_name": "test 3",
        "email_id": "test3@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3,
        "is_active": 1,
        "access_code": null
    },
    {
        "team_details_id": 1,
        "team_name": "Avengers",
        "team_description": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-03T09:31:13.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-03T09:31:13.000Z",
        "created_by": "23",
        "updated_by": null,
        "team_participants_id": 4,
        "user_id": 103,
        "user_name": "test 4",
        "email_id": "test4@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3,
        "is_active": 1,
        "access_code": null
    },
    {
        "team_details_id": 1,
        "team_name": "Avengers",
        "team_description": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-03T09:34:24.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-03T09:34:24.000Z",
        "created_by": "23",
        "updated_by": "23",
        "team_participants_id": 13,
        "user_id": 104,
        "user_name": "test 5",
        "email_id": "test5@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3,
        "is_active": 1,
        "access_code": null
    },
    {
        "team_details_id": 5,
        "team_name": "KantaraBuilders",
        "team_description": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-03T09:35:23.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-03T09:35:23.000Z",
        "created_by": "23",
        "updated_by": null,
        "team_participants_id": 16,
        "user_id": 105,
        "user_name": "test 6",
        "email_id": "test6@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3,
        "is_active": 1,
        "access_code": null
    },
    {
        "team_details_id": 5,
        "team_name": "KantaraBuilders",
        "team_description": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-03T09:35:23.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-03T09:35:23.000Z",
        "created_by": "23",
        "updated_by": null,
        "team_participants_id": 17,
        "user_id": 106,
        "user_name": "test 7",
        "email_id": "test7@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3,
        "is_active": 1,
        "access_code": null
    }
]
```

And I wanted to convert to below format

```
let foramtedResponse = [{
    "team_details_id": 1,
    "team_name": "Avengers",
    "participant_list":[{
        "user_id": 101,
        "user_name": "test 2",
        "email_id": "test2@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3
    },{
        "user_id": 102,
        "user_name": "test 3",
        "email_id": "test3@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3,
    },
    {
        "user_id": 103,
        "user_name": "test 4",
        "email_id": "test4@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3
    },
    {
        "user_id": 104,
        "user_name": "test 5",
        "email_id": "test5@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3
    }]
},
{
    "team_details_id": 5,
    "team_name": "KantaraBuilders",
    "participant_list":[{
        "user_id": 105,
        "user_name": "test 6",
        "email_id": "test6@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3
    },{
        "team_participants_id": 17,
        "user_id": 106,
        "user_name": "test 7",
        "email_id": "test7@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3
    }]
}
]
```

I wanted to do this with the help of map.reduce to reduce to nested array of object and I wanted to match the user_name,user_id and team_details_id for reference.
Please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: `reduceResult` is a function and you are not passing it anything when you are logging. also that function doesnt return anythinig as well so you need to `return result.reduce....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following code for a possible solution. You forgot to add the members to the array and you didnt set the team_details_id.

```js
let result =  [
    {
        "team_details_id": 1,
        "team_name": "Avengers",
        "team_description": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-03T09:31:13.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-03T09:31:13.000Z",
        "created_by": "23",
        "updated_by": null,
        "team_participants_id": 2,
        "user_id": 101,
        "user_name": "test 2",
        "email_id": "test2@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3,
        "is_active": 1,
        "access_code": null
    },
    {
        "team_details_id": 1,
        "team_name": "Avengers",
        "team_description": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-03T09:31:13.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-03T09:31:13.000Z",
        "created_by": "23",
        "updated_by": null,
        "team_participants_id": 3,
        "user_id": 102,
        "user_name": "test 3",
        "email_id": "test3@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3,
        "is_active": 1,
        "access_code": null
    },
    {
        "team_details_id": 1,
        "team_name": "Avengers",
        "team_description": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-03T09:31:13.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-03T09:31:13.000Z",
        "created_by": "23",
        "updated_by": null,
        "team_participants_id": 4,
        "user_id": 103,
        "user_name": "test 4",
        "email_id": "test4@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3,
        "is_active": 1,
        "access_code": null
    },
    {
        "team_details_id": 1,
        "team_name": "Avengers",
        "team_description": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-03T09:34:24.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-03T09:34:24.000Z",
        "created_by": "23",
        "updated_by": "23",
        "team_participants_id": 13,
        "user_id": 104,
        "user_name": "test 5",
        "email_id": "test5@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3,
        "is_active": 1,
        "access_code": null
    },
    {
        "team_details_id": 5,
        "team_name": "KantaraBuilders",
        "team_description": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-03T09:35:23.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-03T09:35:23.000Z",
        "created_by": "23",
        "updated_by": null,
        "team_participants_id": 16,
        "user_id": 105,
        "user_name": "test 6",
        "email_id": "test6@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3,
        "is_active": 1,
        "access_code": null
    },
    {
        "team_details_id": 5,
        "team_name": "KantaraBuilders",
        "team_description": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-03T09:35:23.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-03T09:35:23.000Z",
        "created_by": "23",
        "updated_by": null,
        "team_participants_id": 17,
        "user_id": 106,
        "user_name": "test 7",
        "email_id": "test7@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3,
        "is_active": 1,
        "access_code": null
    }
]

const reduceResult = (result) =>
  result.reduce((data, item) => {
    let team_details = data.find(p => p.team_details_id === item.team_details_id);
    if (!team_details) {
      team_name = { 
      team_details_id: item.team_details_id, 
      team_name: item.team_name, 
      team_participants: [
          {
            user_id: item.user_id, 
            user_name: item.user_name,
            email_id: item.email_id,
            role_id: item.role_id,
          }
        ] 
      }
      data.push(team_name);
    } else {
      team_details.team_participants.push(
      {
            user_id: item.user_id, 
            user_name: item.user_name,
            email_id: item.email_id,
            role_id: item.role_id,
          }
          )
    }
    return data;
  }, []);

  console.log("reduceResult:-",reduceResult(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

you are correct in thinking the `array.reduce` method is what you need here. First use the reduce method to create an object where the team names are the keys and all the players are added into this object. Then use the `Object.values` method to transform the object into an array and it matches your desired data structure.

```js
let result =  [
    {
        "team_details_id": 1,
        "team_name": "Avengers",
        "team_description": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-03T09:31:13.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-03T09:31:13.000Z",
        "created_by": "23",
        "updated_by": null,
        "team_participants_id": 2,
        "user_id": 101,
        "user_name": "test 2",
        "email_id": "test2@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3,
        "is_active": 1,
        "access_code": null
    },
    {
        "team_details_id": 1,
        "team_name": "Avengers",
        "team_description": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-03T09:31:13.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-03T09:31:13.000Z",
        "created_by": "23",
        "updated_by": null,
        "team_participants_id": 3,
        "user_id": 102,
        "user_name": "test 3",
        "email_id": "test3@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3,
        "is_active": 1,
        "access_code": null
    },
    {
        "team_details_id": 1,
        "team_name": "Avengers",
        "team_description": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-03T09:31:13.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-03T09:31:13.000Z",
        "created_by": "23",
        "updated_by": null,
        "team_participants_id": 4,
        "user_id": 103,
        "user_name": "test 4",
        "email_id": "test4@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3,
        "is_active": 1,
        "access_code": null
    },
    {
        "team_details_id": 1,
        "team_name": "Avengers",
        "team_description": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-03T09:34:24.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-03T09:34:24.000Z",
        "created_by": "23",
        "updated_by": "23",
        "team_participants_id": 13,
        "user_id": 104,
        "user_name": "test 5",
        "email_id": "test5@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3,
        "is_active": 1,
        "access_code": null
    },
    {
        "team_details_id": 5,
        "team_name": "KantaraBuilders",
        "team_description": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-03T09:35:23.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-03T09:35:23.000Z",
        "created_by": "23",
        "updated_by": null,
        "team_participants_id": 16,
        "user_id": 105,
        "user_name": "test 6",
        "email_id": "test6@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3,
        "is_active": 1,
        "access_code": null
    },
    {
        "team_details_id": 5,
        "team_name": "KantaraBuilders",
        "team_description": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-03T09:35:23.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-03T09:35:23.000Z",
        "created_by": "23",
        "updated_by": null,
        "team_participants_id": 17,
        "user_id": 106,
        "user_name": "test 7",
        "email_id": "test7@gmail.com",
        "role_id": 3,
        "is_active": 1,
        "access_code": null
    }
]

const dataInObjectStructure = result.reduce((agg, item) => {
  if (agg[item.team_name]) {
    agg[item.team_name].participant_list.push(
    {
        user_id: item.user_id,
        user_name: item.user_name,
        email_id: item.email_id,
        role_id: item.role_id,
      }
    )
  } else {
    agg[item.team_name] = {
      team_details_id: item.team_details_id,
      team_name: item.team_name,
      participant_list:[{
        user_id: item.user_id,
        user_name: item.user_name,
        email_id: item.email_id,
        role_id: item.role_id,
      }]
    }
  }
  return agg
}, {})

const dataInArrayFormat = Object.values(dataInObjectStructure);

console.log(dataInArrayFormat)
```